# Calculate the sum and average of a fixed number of iterative consecutive rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

```
|  ID  |    Date    |    Value     |
------------------------------------
|  A   | 01-01-2020 |    0.4854    |
|  A   | 02-01-2020 |    0.4856    |
|  A   | 03-01-2020 |    0.3982    |
---
|  A   | 29-12-2020 |    0.2139    |
|  A   | 30-12-2020 |    0.6290    |
|  A   | 31-12-2020 |    1.3921    |
---
|  B   | 01-01-2020 |    2.198     |
|  B   | 02-01-2020 |    1.4856    |
|  B   | 03-01-2020 |    2.3982    |
---
```

For a given ID, I need to find the sum and average of "Value" for all 14 day periods and then return the sum and average along with the start date and end date. Let's say, 01-01-2020 to 14-01-2020 is a 14 day period and its sum of "Value" is 3.27 and average of "Value" is 0.4239, then 02-01-2020 to 15-01-2020 is another 14 day period and its sum of "Value" is 3.34 and average of "Value" is 0.4456.. likewise I need to find the sum and average of all possible consecutive 14 day periods. The 14 day period needs to be consecutive.

My output should look like:

```
|  ID  | Start Date |  End Date  |   Sum   |  Average  |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  A   | 01-01-2020 | 14-01-2020 | 3.2685  |   0.4239  |
|  A   | 02-01-2020 | 15-01-2020 | 3.3371  |   0.4456  |
|  A   | 03-01-2020 | 16-01-2020 | 3.1982  |   0.3987  |
---
|  B   | 01-01-2020 | 14-01-2020 | 4.2685  |   0.6321  |
|  B   | 02-01-2020 | 15-01-2020 | 5.3371  |   0.7892  |
|  B   | 03-01-2020 | 16-01-2020 | 4.1982  |   0.6210  |
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to add a new column for the end date to the data frame. I use `iterows()` to extract the rows in the data frame on a row-by-row basis to calculate the sum and average.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import datetime

date_rng = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-31', freq='1D')
date_rng = date_rng.append(date_rng)
# value = np.random.uniform(0, 5, 62)
value = np.random.randint(0, 5, (62,))
Id = ['A']*31+['B']*31
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':Id,'date':date_rng,'Value':value+value[::-1]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['End Date'] = df['date']+ datetime.timedelta(days=13)
df.columns = ['ID', 'Start Date', 'Value', 'End Date']
import itertools
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    start = row['Start Date']
    end = row['End Date']
    i = row['ID']
    d = df[(df['ID'] == i) & (df['Start Date'] >= df.loc[idx,'Start Date']) & (df['Start Date'] <= df.loc[idx,'End Date'])]['Value']
    df.loc[idx,'sum'] = d.sum()
    df.loc[idx,'mean'] = d.mean()
df.head(15)

ID  Start Date  Value   End Date    sum mean
0   A   2020-01-01  6   2020-01-14  56.0    4.000000
1   A   2020-01-02  7   2020-01-15  53.0    3.785714
2   A   2020-01-03  1   2020-01-16  50.0    3.571429
3   A   2020-01-04  1   2020-01-17  55.0    3.928571
4   A   2020-01-05  0   2020-01-18  57.0    4.071429
5   A   2020-01-06  5   2020-01-19  60.0    4.285714
6   A   2020-01-07  3   2020-01-20  61.0    4.357143
7   A   2020-01-08  8   2020-01-21  61.0    4.357143
8   A   2020-01-09  4   2020-01-22  55.0    3.928571
9   A   2020-01-10  5   2020-01-23  54.0    3.857143
10  A   2020-01-11  6   2020-01-24  53.0    3.785714
11  A   2020-01-12  6   2020-01-25  52.0    3.714286
12  A   2020-01-13  0   2020-01-26  50.0    3.571429
13  A   2020-01-14  4   2020-01-27  51.0    3.642857
14  A   2020-01-15  3   2020-01-28  51.0    3.642857
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar approach to @r-beginners but this one uses `transform` and calls the function to calculate the sum and mean values.

```
import pandas as pd
date1 = '2011-05-03'
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['start_date'] = pd.date_range(date1, periods=100,freq='D')
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(13, unit='D')
df['score'] = range(1, 1+len(df))

df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])
def sum_scores(d):
    return df[(df['start_date'] <= d) &
              (df['end_date'] >= d)]['score'].sum()

def mean_scores(d):
    return df[(df['start_date'] <= d) &
              (df['end_date'] >= d)]['score'].mean()

df['sum'] = df['end_date'].transform(sum_scores)
df['mean'] = df['end_date'].transform(mean_scores)

print (df)
```

The results from this are:

```
   start_date   end_date  score  sum  mean
0  2011-05-03 2011-05-16      1  105   7.5
1  2011-05-04 2011-05-17      2  119   8.5
2  2011-05-05 2011-05-18      3  133   9.5
3  2011-05-06 2011-05-19      4  147  10.5
4  2011-05-07 2011-05-20      5  161  11.5
5  2011-05-08 2011-05-21      6  175  12.5
6  2011-05-09 2011-05-22      7  189  13.5
7  2011-05-10 2011-05-23      8  203  14.5
8  2011-05-11 2011-05-24      9  217  15.5
9  2011-05-12 2011-05-25     10  231  16.5
10 2011-05-13 2011-05-26     11  245  17.5
11 2011-05-14 2011-05-27     12  259  18.5
12 2011-05-15 2011-05-28     13  273  19.5
13 2011-05-16 2011-05-29     14  287  20.5
14 2011-05-17 2011-05-30     15  301  21.5
15 2011-05-18 2011-05-31     16  315  22.5
16 2011-05-19 2011-06-01     17  329  23.5
17 2011-05-20 2011-06-02     18  343  24.5
18 2011-05-21 2011-06-03     19  357  25.5
19 2011-05-22 2011-06-04     20  371  26.5
```

You can do groupby the `ID` to get this broken down by each ID.